# Does using ./ in paths make sense with common Unix tools?

Tags: shell, path

Throughout the years I've been using `./` in front of absolute paths more and more.
For example:

```
mv ./file /target/
rm ./something/else

# compared to
mv file /target/
rm something/else
```

I've seen it in more places around the web, which is probably why I adapted to using it. I can't seem to understand why this is done though, and have been wondering for a while.
Maybe it's a bad habit originating from calling local binaries directly: `./a.out`

Is the `./` obsolete in the shell example above? Is there any reason to use `./` in *some* cases? Does using it possibly make paths more explicit?

Comment: Here's one reason: [Why cat, grep and other commands can't understand files starting with minus sign?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87355/why-cat-grep-and-other-commands-cant-understand-files-starting-with-minus-sign)

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397524/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bad habit to specify explicitly that something is located in the current directory, especially when that something is a script or program (the alternative in that case would be to have `.` in your `$PATH` which is generally [considered to be a security risk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254711/history-of-unix-not-including-current-directory-in-path)).

There are situations where you will have `./` at the start of a pathname no matter if you want it or not.  For example, the pathnames found by `find` when searching from `.` downwards will always be prefixed by `./`.

In other situations, a filename may interfere with the options of a utility, as when trying to remove a file called `-f` with

```
rm -f
```

Using

```
rm ./-f
```

would solve that (the `./-f` would not be taken as an option to `rm`), as would

```
rm -- -f
```

do (the `--` signals the end of any command line options).

Also note that shell globs, such as `*` may expand to files with an initial dash.  It is therefore safer to e.g. loop over `./*` than over `*` (unless you use `--` to delimit the unknown filename from the options given to utilities).

It is therefore a good idea to use `./` in pathnames, particularly if the pathname is stored in a variable and comes from some source external to the script.

Comment: So that aggregates into it being obsolete, with the exception for some arguably uncommon situations. Thanks!

Comment: @TimVisee If you ever do any amount of shell scripting for other people than yourself, you will run into these "uncommon" situations every once in a while, if not often.