# How to list all JPG files with zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, ls

With bash, I used to executed `ls *.JPG` to list all JPG files of a directory, but since macOS suggested me to move to zsh, this simple command doesn't work anymore and gives me the following error:

```
$ ls *.JPG      
ls: illegal option --  
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]
```

What the appropriate equivalent with zsh ?

Comment: Globbing (ie. `ls *.JPG`) should work in zsh. Remember it's case sensitive, so you may need `ls *.jpg`. If you want to change back to bash, here are the instructions: https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/

Comment: I have plenty of images which extension is upper case `JPG`, but `ls *.JPG` returns `ls: illegal option --  ` and `usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]`.

Comment: @Mark I'd prefer to give `zsh` a try before decided to change back or not to `bash`. I just updated my question.

Comment: You probably have a filename that starts with a hyphen ... try `ls -- *.JPG`

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem indeed.

Comment: Suggesting a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87355/117549

Comment: Should rather be `ls -d -- *.JPG`, or `print -rC1 -- *.JPG` (zsh) as there's no point calling `ls` if it's just to print the arguments.